# Android webview touchmove bug

Tags: android, webview, touch-event

I am developing an Android WebView App and for some reason the "touchmove" event refuses to fire. It works fine on a desktop-browser. How can I fix it? Does not work on the android emulator either.

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
    console.log("touchstart", e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
    console.log("touchmove", e); // <--- refuses to fire
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
    console.log("touchend", e);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do a workaround it like this:

```
var onTouchEnd = function(){
  console.log("touch end");
}
document.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchEnd);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchEnd);
document.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);
```

or

try to console it like this

```
var onTouchEnd = function(){
  console.log("touch end");
  var touch = event.changeTouches[0];
  console.log("touch", touch);
}
document.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchEnd);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchEnd);
document.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd);
```

Comment: Eh no i need the touchmove event to fire.